# Ubuntu does not start due to too little disk space

Tags: dual-boot, uninstall, disk-usage, tmp, umount

In my computer I have 2 disks. I have one that runs Windows 10 and one that has  Ubuntu on it. I also have a partition for my personal files (this is mainly used by Windows so it is a NTFS file system).

Now, Ubuntu does not start because it shows an error which says that there is too little disk space left. Specifically, the error says:

```
failed to create new system journal no space left on device.
```

I tried to start it in recovery mode and run `umount /tmp`, but I get:

```
umount: /tmp: not mounted.
```

I also tried to remove some packages using `apt-get remove package-name`, but then it says there was an error because there is no space left on the device.

I guess I could just get the Ubuntu .iso file and reinstall the OS, but then all my data from there would be lost, because Windows cannot read ext4, so I could not backup my files.

Could someone suggest a solution where I can keep all my files?

Comment: How much space did you allocate?  (greater than the recommended 25gb for a desktop?).  If you add more software, you often find you need more space.  I'd suggest booting a 'live' system (such as Ubuntu install media), navigating to your installed system, and start removing some files until you can use your system normally. Then you can boot & remove more packages etc (`sudo apt autoclean; sudo apt autoremove` etc which will help, but need space to operate).  You didn't tell us what release though.

Comment: I have 17gb for the system and it says 100% is in use. The release version is 18.04.

Comment: The recommended minimum is 25gb for a desktop so if you started adding software to your system, space problems should have been expected (I realize many blogs suggest smaller, but the official site recommends 25gb, I prefer 32gb myself) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements  In your case I'd suggest using terminal (or live system) to remove files as stated in prior comment until you can login normally to remove software, and consider increasing partition to 25gb minimum or greater.

Comment: I could start it now. Thank you!